# MySQL UPDATE .. WHERE IN .. RAND() .. LIMIT

Tags: mysql, random, sql-update

Ok, that's a weird query, i know:

```
UPDATE `entries`
SET `winner` = 1
WHERE `subscriber_id` IN (19, 128, 127, 125, 150)
ORDER BY RAND()
LIMIT 3
```

`subscriber_id`s are definitely presented, all winner field values are 0.

Sometimes it'll update all 3 rows, sometimes less, and it could happen it doesn't update anything.

When i'll use `EXPLAIN` in this query it gives me the totally useless `Error Code: 1064. You have an error in your SQL syntax;` error.

Could you confirm (or deny) that's my query is valid? Why it producing different results mentioned above?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Can you confirm that all winner fields are different than 1. May be it tries to update rows that already have been set to 1. Otherwise it seems OK. The EXPLAIN statement works only with SELECT statements on MySQL servers older than 5.6 so this might be the reason it fails

Comment: Yes, all winner fields are 0.